# How to show actual result for floating-point division in C?

Tags: c, floating-point, output, printf, division

I am learning the C programming language and, in Xcode 13.x, when I write this:

```
float a = 3 / 2;
float b = 1 / 3;
printf("3 divided by 2 as a float is %f, 1 divided by 3 as a float is %f\n", a, b);
```

The console shouts out this:
`3 divided by 2 as a float is 1.000000, 1 divided by 3 as a float is 0.000000`

I would expect it to show `1.500000` and `0.333333`, but why doesn't it?
I am sure the solution is obvious and simple but basic googling/searching did not help.
I tried to `#include float.h` thinking it would have helped but no luck there.
What am I blindly missing?
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are obviously trying to store the result of the division into a `float`, but floats also include integers.
You're actually performing an integer division, because, in both cases, both of your terms are integers (don't have a fractional part).
The division is performed rounded (result being without a fractional part), and is assigned to your variable.

How to correct this?
Try adding a fractional part to at least one of the two numbers. For example:

```
float a = 3.0/2;
```

This should do it.